# Android genymotion not working -Saying unable to start the Virtual device

Tags: android, genymotion

I am using Genymotion for debug application but it gives me error of

```
Unable to start the Virtual device

VirtualBox can not start the virtual device
```

[image: Like this]

I am not able to find the problem why this happens?

Comment: make sure that u have installed Oracle VM VirtualBox..

Comment: go with @MSGadag's Solution..

Comment: it usually happens. go with @msgadag's solution. You can also start your genymotion first.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem, you can try:

1. Close all genymotion, and restart.
2. Install or reinstall the Virtual box [here](https://www.virtualbox.org).